# lefschetz hyperplane theorem in positive characteristic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, hodge-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory

The proof of the Lefschetz Hyperplane theorem over $\mathbb{C}$ is well-known, and relies on Hodge theory in an important way. Does there exist an analogue of this theorem in positive characteristic, for an appropriate cohomology theory (crystalline? rigid?)?

Comment: For the etale topology, the weak Lefschetz theorem is a standard result, which can be found in the usual texts, but the hard Lefschetz theorem was only proved by Deligne as a result of his proof of the Weil conjectures (see the Wikipedia).